# C++: Namespace std and string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to emulate the behavior of `std::` and the `#include <string>` to better understand `namespaces` and `dependencies`, etc...

In an empty project, if I use `std::` no options appear, however declaring `#include <string>`, now when doing `std::` a new set of options appear including string `std::string` of course...

I was trying to emulate this `namespace` resolution so I can better understand how this all works...

So, if my nsRoot1 (in code below) represented something like `std namespace`, how I would include a new `<string class>` behavior that is only available when I use the `#include <string>`.

```
namespace nsRoot1 {

}

namespace nsString {

    class mCls2
    {
    public:
        mCls2();
        ~mCls2();

    private:

    };
}

#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string str;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's a different example of trying to emulate the same behavior.
How is std able to separate the string class in a different header file that only becomes available when we use the #include

```
// main.cpp
#include "myStd.h"

int main()
{
    mySTD::myStr aa;
    aa.ToLower();

}

// myStd.h 
#pragma once
namespace mySTD
{
    class myStr
    {
    public:
        myStr();
        ~myStr();
        void ToLower(){}
    private:

    };
}
```

With your help I was able to emulate What I wanted, so here's the result that I come up with...

```
// main.cpp
#include "myStd.h"
#include "myString.h"

int main()
{
    mySTD::myStr aa;
    aa.ToLower();
}

// mySTD.h
#pragma once
namespace mySTD
{
}

// myStr.h

#pragma once
namespace mySTD
{
    class myStr
    {
    public:
        myStr();
        ~myStr();
        void ToLower() {}
    private:

    };
}
```

Thank you...

Comment: hi, I'm using Visual Studio, empty project no pre compiled headers

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to modify the behavior of standard library headers, why are you trying to add your own class to it?

Comment: What I don-t understand is how string class only appears after I include the header file. My understanding is when you declare a namespace all class in that namespace become available without needing to include anyother header... So how namespace std is able to separate string class in a different header file?

Comment: _"My understanding is when you declare a namespace all class in that namespace become available without needing to include anyother header"_ Your understanding is wrong. `using namespace` provides a shortcut for name resolution, nothing more. The actual features are made available by `#include` (otherwise what would the `#include` be for?)

Comment: I updated my sample, perhaps is now more clear. From that last sample how can I emulate the same behavior in std::string using #include?

Comment: How is your new example not doing exactly that?

Comment: Well, when I #include mySTD.h all classes are immediately available, but when using a clean project I 1st have std:: namespace available and then I add new classes while adding <string>, <iostream>, etc... which are only available when I use the #include. So I can I include mySTD first WITHOUT making available all CLASES inside that namepspace and then include 1 by 1 as needed using #include files?

Comment: @J_PT Sure, just put your classes in different header files.

Comment: You only have a single `class` inside your namespace. Try creating a second header that declares more classes inside `namespace mySTD`

Comment: If I include a second header file with myStr class in a different header file, I CAN'T (I don't know how) relate it with mySTD namespace. If I use #include myStr.h inside mySTD namespace, I get the same behavior... If I include myStr.h inside my main.cpp it has no relation with mySTD namespace...

Comment: ops.. I think I got it, thank you for your help guys :)

Comment: I was not including the second header file with the same namespace mySTd in the second header file.. I didn't know that was possible... very cool :)

Comment: Just a small comment: remember to not confuse what your IDE makes easily available in drop-down boxes and similar with what the compiler will actually see and be able to resolve - the two are often quite different. The IDE is just trying to be helpful, but it is *not* representative of *final truth*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? My understanding is that, the compiler will merge both headers with the same declared namespace in a single obj file, and the advantage of doing this in a large project is that you can save space an time to load these functions  as long as you don't need all of them, and you control that by #including or not portions of that code with the same namespace name. Example, if I have a large namespace with lots of classes, methods, macros, etc.. accross multiple files, I can use the #include to only include the ones that I need in final compilation, Is this not correct?